# Dialog with radio button not works onClick()

Tags: java, android, radio-button, android-alertdialog

I have an item in my menu

```
case R.id.theme:
   ShowRadioDialog();           
 return true;
```

With a method that shows an Alert dialog with 3 radio buttons. When i click the item the dialog shows but when i choose some item inside the dialog and i tap in the positiove buttons nothing happens. This is the method:

```
public void ShowRadioDialog() {
        final CharSequence[] items={"Rosso","Verde","Blu"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Seleziona un colore");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            if (wich== 1) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(MainActivity.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                            toolbar.setBackgroundColor(MainActivity.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Rosso OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.i("Colors", "Rosso Ok");
                        }
                } else if (wich ==2) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(MainActivity.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.green_welcome));
                    }
                } else if (wich == 3){
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(MainActivity.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark_blue));
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items,-1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if ("Rosso".equals(items[which])) {
                        which = 1;
                    } else if ("Verde".equals(items[which])) {

                        which = 2;
                    } else if ("Blu".equals(items[which])) {

                        which = 3;
                    }

            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

I'm not sure it's the correct way. However, not either one (log in the logcat and the Toast in the application) appears. Seems that the positive button not accept the choice. Something is wrong?

Comment: any difference between `which` and `wich`? which you are using on Positive Button Click

Comment: It's only a typing error sorry.. Are the same for real..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a variable on top level and use that to access the selected item.

`int index = -1;`

```
public void ShowRadioDialog() {
    final CharSequence[] items={"Rosso","Verde","Blu"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Seleziona un colore");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        if (index == 1) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(MainActivity.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(MainActivity.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Rosso OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i("Colors", "Rosso Ok");
                    }
            } else if (index ==2) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(MainActivity.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.green_welcome));
                }
            } else if (index == 3){
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(MainActivity.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark_blue));
                }
            }
        }
    });

    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items,-1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if ("Rosso".equals(items[which])) {
                    index = 1;
                } else if ("Verde".equals(items[which])) {

                    index = 2;
                } else if ("Blu".equals(items[which])) {

                    index = 3;
                }

        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

If you want to save the value of `index` in shared preference on click of ok button do like this

Store in SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myPref", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("choice", index);
editor.commit();
```

Fetch from SharedPreferences when required

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myPref", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
int index = preferences.getInt("choice",-1);
```

Comment: Yeah! Now it works thanks! is there a way to save in the sharedpreferences the choice?

Comment: of course you can save it there. This would give you and idea how to do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values

Comment: mmh i'm not pretty sure how can i do it inside a dialog with the radio buttons for real..are you able to show me please? Thank you so much really!

Comment: mmh ok so after all if clause in onClick of positive button, i paste the code to store and in my onCreate Activity the code to fetch..but not works :(

Comment: mmh ok no wait, using a log i saw that it works.. it saves the correct position but not do what it have to do in that option. I don't know if you have understand what i mean

Comment: Please post a new question for that and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67634/discussion-between-rohit5k2-and-end-game).

Comment: ok, but it's simple. Now i post the question and i will write you here the new link to the quest.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27640219/dialog-with-radio-button-save-sharedpreferences-but-not-the-behaviour